# Can I code a Java program that will call a program in another language (Rust) to do some calculations?

Tags: java, jvm

I'd like to make a simulation, but I'd like to write the code to display the state of the simulation and the user interaction (frontend?) in Java (Kotlin actually, but I don't think it is relevant here) for the JVM, and I'd like to write the actual code of the simulation (backend?) in Rust. Mostly because I think it would be neat and that I would learn something.
Can I achieve this, and if yes, how? It might be relevant that the data that needs to be exchanged between the two programs is just a fixed-size array of floats.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

A Rust program compiles to native code (executable or shared library). To call native code from Java you have to use JNI: https://www.baeldung.com/jni.

You may find the jni crate useful for the Rust side of the project: https://docs.rs/jni/0.16.0/jni/